# Trying to to hold animation while jumping then end it when he hits the ground

Tags: unity

What I want is the single frame of animation to hold while in the air then for it to go back to idle when my character hits the ground.

my script right now is

public class CharacterAnim : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator anim;

```
void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        anim.SetTrigger("jump");
    }
}
```

}

Anything is appreciated

Comment: How have you set up your animations and control graph to support this so far? Don't forget to format your code too.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided much information to go on, but assuming you have already set up your animation controller, I have the falling state set up as below

[image]

As you can see in my movement layer, I have three blend tree's for Idle(Not moving) Upright Movement (Walking, Running) and Crouched Movement, but more importantly for your question as you see off to the left I have my **falling** and **landing** state, you can enter the **falling** state (which is just a small very animation set to loop) from **any** other state while the condition **IsGrounded** is **false**.

This means I can Trigger the jump animation (then somewhere physically move my character up) and the animation plays 'automatically' because grounded is now false, this works well because now even if you didn't jump but walked off the edge of something tall you would still transition into the falling state.

To check if I am grounded I do a small raycast down from my character to see if I hit anything with a collider, if I do, **IsGrounded** equals **true**, otherwise I must be falling

*(this isn't entirely the case as I could have my character positioned in such a way I am actually stood on something but the ray hits nothing such as standing near a ledge you can fix that by firing a raycast from each foot and checking the results of both)*

```
public override bool IsEntityGrounded()
{
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector3.up, out RaycastHit hitInfo, groundCheckLength))
    {
        isGrounded = true;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        isGrounded = false;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then when **IsGrounded** becomes **true** again(because the raycast is now hitting the ground) it transitions to Landing which plays a small animation showing the character going from the falling animation to the landing animation.